# Private sale available by link

Tags: magento2.3, price, sales

I want to make possibility to make private sales available by link **for not logged-in** users and for logged in too). 
Example: we have ads with "special prices for new users only" or sending mails to our best premium ultra super members. There are different prices for some products in pool of this offers.

Customers who visited us by this special link should see special prices for all products taking part in offer(product page, cart, etc), if customer login in-prices should not be changed to default prices. What is the best tactic for make this script? Thanks.

Comment: use customer-groups

Comment: @PhilippSander , how about guests? how can i set customer group to not logged-in guest?